# a mistake Gson parse a String like "\"abc\"ab"

Tags: android, json

```
String d = gson.fromJson("\"abc\"", String.class);
String d = gson.fromJson("aa\"abc\"aaa", String.class);
they are right

String d = gson.fromJson("\"abc\"aaa", String.class);
this is wrong
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 7 path $
```

Why the String like "\"abc\"aaa" is malformed JSON?

Comment: "\" here its not correct at the starting of String value. it should be "\'abc\'aaa"

Comment: "\'abc\'aaa" is wrong too,malformed JSON.